# Passing parent_id to a comment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

In my app I have Posts which have comments. Now I also want to add comments to those comments (nested commenting).

I currently do it like this, but it does not write my parent_id to the database:

My comment link in my _comment.html.erb partial:

```
<%= link_to "Comment", new_post_comment_path(comment.post, parent_id: comment.id) %>
```

My comments/new.html.erb:

```
<%= form_for [@post, Comment.new] do |f| %>
    <%= f.hidden_field :parent_id %>
    <%= f.text_area :body %>
    <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

My comments_controller.rb:

```
  def new
    @post=Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment = Comment.new(parent_id: params[:parent_id])
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @comment=@post.comments.build(comment_params)
    @comment.user=current_user
    if @comment.save
        redirect_to :back
  end 

  private

  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:body, :parent_id)
  end
```

Query that gets executed:

```
INSERT INTO "comments" ("body", "created_at", "post_id", "updated_at", "user_id") VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4, $5, $6) RETURNING "id"
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Ancestry**

I was going to give you an idea as to how you could assign the `parent_id` as you need, but considering we've created a *comments system* before, I felt it better to give you some systemic ideas; rather than specifics

We use a gem called [`Ancestry`](https://github.com/stefankroes/ancestry) to give us the ability to nest our objects:

[image]

This gives us the flexibility to create much more robust nesting structures (which I'll detail in a minute):

```
#config/routes.rb
resources :posts do
   resources :comments, only: [:new, :create] do
      get :reply #-> domain.com/posts/:post_id/comments/:id/reply
   end
end

#app/controllers/comments_controller.rb
Class CommentsController < ApplicationController
   def new
      @post = Post.find params[:post_id]
      @comment = Comment.new
   end

   def reply
      @post = Post.find params[:post_id]
      @comment = Comment.new
      @parent = params[:id]

      render :new
   end

   def create
      @post = Post.find params[:post_id]
      @comment = @post.comments.new comment_params
      @comment.save
   end

   private

   def comment_params
      params.require(:comment).permit(:body, :ancestry)
   end
end


#app/views/comments/new.html.erb
<%= form_for [@post, @comment] do |f| %>
   <%= f.text_field :body %>
   <%= f.hidden_field :ancestry, value: @parent if @parent.present? %>
   <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

---

The beauty of using `ancestry` (the real reason for my recommendation) is the ability to then create a truly nested view:

[image]

To do this, you can use the partial we created:

```
#app/comments/index.html.erb
<%= render partial: "category", collection: @comments, as: :collection %>

#app/comments/_comment.html.erb
<% collection.arrange.each do |comment, sub_item| %>
        <li>
            <%= link_to comment.title, comment_path(comment) %>
            <% if comment.has_children? %>
                <%= render partial: "comment", locals: { collection: comment.children } %>
            <% end %>
        </li>
<% end %>
```

--

**Dropdown**

[image]

```
#app/helpers/application_helper.rb
def nested_dropdown(items)
        result = []
        items.map do |item, sub_items|
            result << [('- ' * item.depth) + item.name, item.id]
            result += nested_dropdown(sub_items) unless sub_items.blank?
        end
    result
end


#app/views/posts/new.html.erb
<%= form_for @post do |f| %>
   <%= f.select(:category_ids, nested_dropdown(Category.all.arrange), prompt: "Category", selected: @category ) %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Well what do you know. I tried using ancestry before, but your guide was a little different so I tried it again. Worked like a charm! Thanks.

Comment: Wow thanks for the compliment! Love the fact it worked! Would you like the "nested dropdown" helper we made too?

Comment: Actually I would love it. I was just about to hand code it from scratch :)

Comment: +1. This has been done enough times before that we shouldn't be re-inventing the wheel when we can use mostly-canned solutions like Ancestry.

Comment: Yep, but you have to remember that finding up-to-date is actually pretty difficult, especially for the "nested dropdown" and "nested partial" :)

Answer (score 0):

Make form for comments as the following:

```
<%= form_for @comment do |f| %>
  <%= f.hidden_field :parent_id, @post.id %>
  <%= f.text_area :body %>
  <%= f.submit %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: This does not work. I get an error undefined method `comments_path' (because my Posts have many comments). If I do forms_for[@posts,@comment] I get an error saying undefined method `merge' for 3364:Fixnum for the f.hidden_field

Comment: actually u can set post url for this form, can u write what's the post/put urls for comments for new/edit actions?

Comment: Read about [form_for](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper.html#method-i-form_for)